# WordPress Contact form 7 IP to Location in email

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using `[_remote_ip]` in the email I am reciveng from contact form 7, is there is a way to show the country name or flag instead of the received IP number?

The main issue started when I activated caching, where the php country locate stopped working, so I have to use the `[_remote_ip]` in the email to know the location of the contact, but it's not a good solution that I always have to locate the ip manually.

That's why I want to check if there is a way to show that IP as a name or as a flag.

Comment: There's a plugin that can do this. https://wordpress.org/plugins/geoip-detect/

Comment: Hi Howard, thank you so much for reply, it doesnt work, 
is it the only option we have ?, or there is another way to show the ip as a city name instaid ? 
what i did now is add the ip website before the ip code like this:
https://ipinfo.io/[_remote_ip]
but its not that efficient

Thanks again :)

Comment: I mean... there are alternative options.  Are you using WooCommerce?  You could tap into the geoloation from it. But really, the best thing would be to build your own Contact Form 7 - form tag.

Comment: Hi again, no am not using WooCommerce :), i am not that good with coding things :)
i have also tried to make a uniq id submisstion for my contact form with a code not a plugin and i was not able to fix it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

This will add a form tag to Contact form 7 `[country]` - Add this to your functions.php or make it a plugin. TO use this, you'll need a subscription (free tier available) to https://ipstack.com.

```php
add_action('wpcf7_init', function (){
    wpcf7_add_form_tag( 'country' , 'cf7_ip_to_country_form_tag' );
}); 
function cf7_ip_to_country_form_tag($tag){
    // Your API Key for https://ipstack.com is required
    $api_key = 'xxxxxxx';
    // Get API Response
    $url = 'http://api.ipstack.com/' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . '?access_key=' . $api_key;    
    $response = wp_remote_get($url);
    $body = json_decode(wp_remote_retrieve_body($response));
    
    /* $body = Object returned from ipstack. 
    * $body->country_name = Full Country Name
    * $body->country_code = 2 Letter ISO Abbrev
    * set the value based on what you want.
    */
    
    return '<input type="hidden" name="country" value="'.$body->country_name.'">';
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, you are so kind, 
i have tried to do it, but i think there is something wrong i did, while adding the api to the function.

i have created an account and lets say the API Access Key for example is : ABC12345
please rewrite the above code for me, so i will copy and paste in the function.
big thanks and am so sorry for disturbing you :)

Comment: Paste your api key instead of the xxxxx

Comment: Ho Howard, 
shall i keep the brackets  '  ' and aste the api between them ?
and do i keep this as it is  '?access_key='
thank you so much :)

Comment: you must write `'your_api_key'` within the ' ' yes...

Comment: Hi man, 
it didnt work :(, 
i did exactly what you ask me to do, i can see that the api call is working (https://ibb.co/6Hj1NNB) , but the email sent doesnt show the country it only shows the [country_name], that i use in the email form

Comment: I've updated the answer.  use 'country' rather than 'country_name' and it works.  The email doesn't like underscores.  I've tested this, and it is working.

Comment: Hi Howard, thank you so much for reply, can we have anyother name, like countryip ?
i have already a field called called country, could you pleae name to flag or anyother name? 

i have tried it on a new form where the country is not there, and this is the result, i have cut half od the api to see how i did it.
https://ibb.co/k6XHy26

Comment: Sure change it to countryip.  Replace `country` with `countryip` in all instances.